# Unable to fetch a random number from chainlink VRF. Can someone help

Tags: solidity, dapps, chainlink, randomness, chainlink-vrf

array of `randomWords` is set 0 in the function `requestRandomWords()`

```
 s_requests[requestId] = RequestStatus({
            randomWords: new uint256[](0),
            exists: true,
            fulfilled: false
        })
```

there is no option to view `randomWords`

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// An example of a consumer contract that relies on a subscription for funding.
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ConfirmedOwner.sol";

/**
 * Request testnet LINK and ETH here: https://faucets.chain.link/
 * Find information on LINK Token Contracts and get the latest ETH and LINK faucets here: https://docs.chain.link/docs/link-token-contracts/
 */

/**
 * THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT THAT USES HARDCODED VALUES FOR CLARITY.
 * THIS IS AN EXAMPLE CONTRACT THAT USES UN-AUDITED CODE.
 * DO NOT USE THIS CODE IN PRODUCTION.
 */

contract VRFv2Consumer is VRFConsumerBaseV2, ConfirmedOwner {
    event RequestSent(uint256 requestId, uint32 numWords);
    event RequestFulfilled(uint256 requestId, uint256[] randomWords);

    struct RequestStatus {
        bool fulfilled; // whether the request has been successfully fulfilled
        bool exists; // whether a requestId exists
        uint256[] randomWords;
    }
    mapping(uint256 => RequestStatus)
        public s_requests; /* requestId --> requestStatus */

        //mumbai co-ordinator
    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface COORDINATOR;

    // Your subscription ID.
    uint64 s_subscriptionId;

    // past requests Id.
    uint256[] public requestIds;
    uint256 public lastRequestId;

    // The gas lane to use, which specifies the maximum gas price to bump to.
    // For a list of available gas lanes on each network,
    // see https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf/v2/subscription/supported-networks/#configurations
    bytes32 keyHash =
       0x83250c5584ffa93feb6ee082981c5ebe484c865196750b39835ad4f13780435d;

    // Depends on the number of requested values that you want sent to the
    // fulfillRandomWords() function. Storing each word costs about 20,000 gas,
    // so 100,000 is a safe default for this example contract. Test and adjust
    // this limit based on the network that you select, the size of the request,
    // and the processing of the callback request in the fulfillRandomWords()
    // function.
    uint32 callbackGasLimit = 2_500_000;

    // The de-fault is 3, but you can set this higher.
    uint16 requestConfirmations = 3;

    // For this example, retrieve 2 random values in one request.
    // Cannot exceed VRFCoordinatorV2.MAX_NUM_WORDS.
    uint32 numWords = 2;

    /**
     * HARDCODED FOR MUMBAI
     * COORDINATOR: 0x7a1BaC17Ccc5b313516C5E16fb24f7659aA5ebed
     */
    constructor(
        uint64 subscriptionId
    )
        VRFConsumerBaseV2(0x7a1BaC17Ccc5b313516C5E16fb24f7659aA5ebed)
        ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender)
    {
        COORDINATOR = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(
            0x7a1BaC17Ccc5b313516C5E16fb24f7659aA5ebed
        );
        s_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
    }

    // Assumes the subscription is funded sufficiently.
    function requestRandomWords()
        external
        onlyOwner
        returns (uint256 requestId)
    {
        // Will revert if subscription is not set and funded.
        requestId = COORDINATOR.requestRandomWords(
            keyHash,
            s_subscriptionId,
            requestConfirmations,
            callbackGasLimit,
            numWords
        );
        s_requests[requestId] = RequestStatus({
            randomWords: new uint256[](0),
            exists: true,
            fulfilled: false
        });
        requestIds.push(requestId);
        lastRequestId = requestId;
        emit RequestSent(requestId, numWords);
        return requestId;
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(
        uint256 _requestId,
        uint256[] memory _randomWords
    ) internal override {
        require(s_requests[_requestId].exists, "request not found");
        s_requests[_requestId].fulfilled = true;
        s_requests[_requestId].randomWords = _randomWords;
        emit RequestFulfilled(_requestId, _randomWords);
    }

    function getRequestStatus(
        uint256 _requestId
    ) external view returns (bool fulfilled, uint256[] memory randomWords) {
        require(s_requests[_requestId].exists, "request not found");
        RequestStatus memory request = s_requests[_requestId];
        return (request.fulfilled, request.randomWords);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you have to create two extra mapping  in you contract

```
 mapping(uint256 => uint256) public requestTosenderMapping;
 mapping(uint256 => uint256[]) public randomUpdateMapping;
```

As well as make function an extra function which you have to update you get random number or not

For Example:

```
function isRandomNumberUpdate() public view returns (bool status) {
        if (s_randomWords.length > 0) return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

first request random number requestRandomWords()
and wait a few time 15 sec till confirmation of the block then get all random numbers from this function or `isRandomNumberUpdate` returns `true`

```
function fulfillRandomWords(uint256 requestId, uint256[] memory randomWords)
        internal
        virtual
        override
    {
        s_randomWords = randomWords;
        randomUpdateMapping[requestTosenderMapping[requestId]] = randomWords; // all random values come here
    }
```